# Player object changes position while rotating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all: Sorry for my bad English, I'm Dutch.

I'm trying to create a player object that can walk forward and backwards (with the up and down keys), and rotate the player with the right and left keys. But when I press the left or right key, the position of the player changes, it looks like it rotates around a certain point. But it should rotate and stay on the same place, like I do when I turn around.

I have some other small programs, with the same 'move script' and the same inputmanager settings. There it works fine, so I have no idea why it doesn't work this time.

This is my move script, but this script works fine with other programs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 3f;
    public float rotate = 50f;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    // Update is called once per frame

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Up"))
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.GetButton("Down"))
            transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.GetButton("Right"))
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotate * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.GetButton("Left"))
            transform.Rotate(-Vector3.up, rotate * Time.deltaTime);
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y < 0.01)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
                rb.AddForce(0, 225, 0);
        }

    }

}
```

The InputManager settings (also the same as other programs where it works fine):

[image]

[image]

If someone wants a screenshot of something else of my program, you can always ask it of course. I have no idea what the problem could be, if it isn't in the script or the inputmanager.

Comment: Are you performing your rotation *relative to the centerpoint of the player object* or is it rotating the player around for example his (0,0,0) local coordinate? How is the player model defined?

Comment: Now it is turning around a specific point (like the earth turns around the sun), but it should turn around it's own axes (like the earth turns around his own axes). The player object is a combination (parent) of spheres/cylinders/capsules, the parent player object has a rigidbody and the 'move script'.

Comment: Transform.Rotate performs rotation in local space by default. All other things being equal, it will perform the rotation around the object's local (0,0,0). If that point isn't the center of the player model's geometry, you'd see the behavior you're witnessing. You can try translating prior to rotating if so or adjusting the local coords so you don't have to. To put it another way: let's say you're rotating a flat quarter on the XZ plane around the same Y axis. Are you rotating it by the centerpoint or by the (0,0) in the bottom-left corner?

Comment: Ah okay! On that way. If I understand it correctly, then it's now rotating around the bottom-left corner (if it was a plane), but it should rotate it by the centerpoint. So indeed, that's what goes wrong then

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments in the OP, the solution should be to use:

```
if (Input.GetButton("Right"))
    transform.localEulerAngles = transform.localEulerAngles + new Vector3(xRotation, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
if (Input.GetButton("Left"))
    transform.localEulerAngles = transform.localEulerAngles - new Vector3(xRotation, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
```

Where `xRotation` is a float with the amount you want to rotate per second when and while one of the rotation keys is down.

(PS: Don't have unity open right now, so `+` and `-` might be inverted, but should be something like that.)